# Proving a vector space contains all Borel-measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-measures

> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the collection of all open sets in
>    $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of functions $f :
>  \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
>
> 1) For any $A \in \mathcal{A}$, the function $I_{A}$ belongs to $\mathcal{H}$
>
> 2) $\mathcal{H}$ is a vector space
>
> 3) If $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $0 \leq f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_{n} \in \mathcal{H}$
>
> Prove that $\mathcal{H}$ contains all Borel measurable functions.

This is a measure theory problem that I am having trouble with. I am trying to study for exams but I am really stuck on this problem. By the way, $I_{A}$ is the indicator set function. By vector space, I know that $\mathcal{H}$ has defined operations $+$ and $*$. I don't quite see how that one helps.

I'm thinking (3) can be used in some way sort of like squeeze theorem. But I am really clueless with this problem and I would like to understand it for my exam.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Some of the elements of $\mathcal H$ are of the form $I_A$; I would try to identify what those $A$ are.  Your rules (2) and (3) give you implications are of the form if $I_A$ is in $\mathcal H$, so is $I_{A^c}$, and so on, and so on.

Comment: In 3), does $\lim$ denote pointwise limit everywhere? There seems to be a missing statement that $f_n$ converges.

Comment: The edit doesn't address my question. An increasing sequence does not necessarily converge. Some $f_n(x)$ may tend to $+\infty$. Some information is missing here.

Comment: This seems to be an application of the [functional monotone class theorem](https://planetmath.org/functionalmonotoneclasstheorem), which is proved in some textbooks (e.g. Durrett or D. Williams).  Are you familiar with the ordinary monotone class theorem (for sets)?

Comment: I suspect the correct statement of (3) is: if $f_n$ is a sequence with $f_n \in \mathcal{H}$ for each $n$, and $f_n \le f_{n+1}$ for every $n$, and $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists and is finite for every $x$, then $f \in \mathcal{H}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in comments that you know the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, so here is an outline of how you could proceed. Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be the collection of all sets $A \subset\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $I_A \in H$.

The significance of the vector space property is that whenever you know that two functions $f,g$ are in $H$, then you also know that $af+bg \in H$ for any scalars $a,b$.  In particular, $f+g$ and $f-g$ are in $H$.

a. Observe that $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system.

b. Show that $\mathcal{L}$ is a Dynkin system.

c. Conclude that $H$ contains $I_B$ for every Borel set $B$.

d. Show that $H$ contains every simple function (use the vector space assumption)

e. Show that $H$ contains every nonnegative Borel function (recall that every such function can be written as an increasing limit of simple functions)

f. Show that $H$ contains every Borel function (hint: $f = f^+ - f^-$).

Comment: @ExKo: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Yes, here we are working with $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$.  So you must show that the function $I_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, which is a fancy name for the constant function 1, is in $H$.  But we know that $I_A$ is in $H$ for every open set $A$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set.  So we indeed have $I_{\mathbb{R}^n} \in H$ and thus $\mathbb{R}^n \in \mathcal{L}$.

Comment: @ExKo: The other steps have a similar kind of flavor - they are nothing deep once you pick apart the notation.  For the next part, suppose $A,B \in \mathcal{L}$ with $A \subset B$ (note carefully this added condition in the definition!), and we want to show $A \setminus B \in \mathcal{L}$.  Well, we know that $I_A$ and $I_B$ are in $H$.  How can you write $I_{A \setminus B}$ in terms of $I_A$ and $I_B$?  And having done so, can you see how to use the given assumptions on $H$ to conclude that $I_{A \setminus B} \in H$?

Comment: @ExKo: c to d is just the fact that a simple function is, by very definition, a finite linear combination of indicator functions.  And the fact that $H$ is a vector space says that any finite linear combination of functions from $H$ is again in $H$.

Comment: @ExKo: One other thing: in case it is not clear, when they say "H is a vector space" in this context, they mean it is a vector space *with respect to the usual operations of pointwise addition and scalar multiplication*.  These are not some abstract operations, they are just the ordinary $+$ and $\cdot$ you use every day.

Comment: I tried to write $\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus A = \mathbb{R}^{n} \cap A^{C}$ and got nowhere

Comment: @ExKo: It's simply the fact that $I_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A} = 1 - I_A$.  Just note that if $x \in A$ then $I_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A}(x) = 0$ and $1 - I_A(x) = 0$ as well, and similarly if $x \notin A$ then both sides equal 1.  Now, since $A \in \mathcal{L}$ we have $I_A \in H$.  We also have $1 \in H$ because $1 = I_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ is open.  Finally, $H$ is a vector space, so $1-I_A$ is in $H$ as well.  We have thus shown $I_{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A} \in H$, which means that $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A \in \mathcal{L}$.